# Error using WinJs.XHR to call service

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, windows-store

I'm trying to call a webservice using WinJs.XHR in a windows 8 app; the code works fine when I'm not using firewall; However when I'm using firewall I got the following error:

```
**Forbidden ( Forefront TMG denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL).  )**
```

any clue?

```
  WinJS.Promise.timeout(50000, WinJS.xhr({
        url: "<Service_URL>"

    })
        .then(function (rss) {


        }, function (onRError) {

            });
        },
        function progress(result) {

        }) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not exist any more, all what I did was adding the internet(Client/Server) and Private networking and them removed them.

Not sure if it was something with the code or the ISA server/client .

Answer (score 0):

That might be hard to determine without seeing the URL.  I would bet a character in the URL is being rejected by the firewall.  You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what the URL is with the firewall off/on.

Comment: I checked on the ISA server; what is happening is with all urls because the request is sent with anonymous credentials; so the isa blocks the calls however if I used the same url in browser it works because my credentials are sent with the request.

Comment: Is there way to force the request to use my windows credentials so the request bypasses the firewall safely?

Comment: I think you may need to work with the administrator of your corporate firewall to determine the best way to make this work. If it's HTTP, it should just work...you can use a browser on this network, yes? If so, an HTTP call via XHR should work, unless your firewall only has exceptions for HTTP traffic from specific applications.

Comment: @devhammer ; yes it works in normal browser; but not from the winJs.XHR; the reason from the firewall server that the user send is **anonymous** while from normal browser it has my domain user name

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out the enterpriseAuthentication capability described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx

I have not used it, but it might give you what you need.

Comment: I've tried it before with other capabilities but with no luck.